# FFmpeg streaming: problems with device name

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, encoding, video-streaming, video-capture

I'm trying to stream web camera and microphone in Windows using FFmpeg. First, I get my devices names (to specify -i parameter in streaming command) using a command like this:

ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy

The problem is in wrong encoding of my microphone name:
[image]

How can I add this device to "audio" parameter (Copying this name into "audio" gives no result)?

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: rename it in the windows registry?

Comment: What is that name *supposed* to be, character wise? What is the output after that line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also get stuck with this problem and find solution, and maybe it would help anyone in future.
You just need to open regedit and find "Realtek" (or any other part of device name), one of the results would be like on the screenshot below. Just open "FriendlyName" parameter and rename your device as you wish.

Screenshot:

[image]